# If 90% of crows are black and 10% are red. So in a row of crows, what is the probablity that all of them are black?

Tags: probability, statistics

If 90% of crows are black and 10% are red. So in a row of crows, what is the probablity that all of them are black ? How do I solve this. Thank you.

Comment: I would say use a binomial probability distribution.

Comment: If there are $2$ crows in the row, the probability would be $(.9)^2$.  If there are $3$ crows in the row, the probability would be $(.9)^3$.  I am making the simplifying assumption that the color of a crow is to be regarded as an independent event with respect to the color of a neighboring crow in the same row.  The problem can't be solved unless you know how many crows there are in the row.

Comment: There seems to be [some evidence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooded_crow#Genetic_difference_from_carrion_crows) that crows may prefer to associate with crows of the same colour (usually black or grey), so independence may be a strong assumption

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer**

If we have a row of $n$ crows then the probability of them all being black is equal to $0.9^n$. For example, if we had a row of 5 crows, the probability of all 5 being black is $0.9^5$

**Theory behind the answer**

This result follows on from the Binomial distribution.

In this case we can say that a random variable X (representing whether a crow is red or black) with N trials and fixed probability of success P follows the binomial distribution since the colour of the crows are independent.

If we want to find the probability of Y crows being black and Z crows being red, then the we can use the probability mass function $f_x(x) = nC_Y$ $(0.9)^Y$ $(0.1)^Z$ which simplifies in your question to the form given above in my answer.

You can read more about how we derive the probability mass function on the Wikipedia page for the [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution)

*(Note: I have used $nC_Y$ above to denote the [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) for n crows in total)*